# How to parse invalid options?

Tags: bash

I am writing the following script to parse some options:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $# > 1 ]]
do
key="$1"
case $key in
    -i|--inbound)
        inbound="true"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    -o|--outbound)
        outbound="true"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    *)
        echo "hola"
        exit 1

    ;;
esac
shift # past argument or value
done
echo $inbound
echo $outbound
```

The problem is that i would like to terminate the program, if I receive an invalid option, I tried the following:

```
*)
            exit 1
            echo "invalid option"


        ;;
```

but when i run the program like this: bash script.sh -invalid, anything happens, i would like to appreciate any suggestion to fix this, my desired output would like to:

```
invalid option
```

Comment: Not the issue but `>` is for string comparisons in `[`/`[[`. You want `-gt` or `(( $# > 1 ))`. Add `set -x` to your script (or run `bash -x script.sh ...`) and you should see at least one problem with your logic (and why `bash script.sh -invalid` isn't doing anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `while [[ $# > 1 ]]`

should be

```
while (($# >= 1))
```

1. You want a numeric comparison, not a string comparison. Although in this case, it doesn't make any difference, it would make a big difference if you had compared with `2`, since the string `10` is less than the string `2`.
2. Anyway, if you invoke your script with one argument, `$#` will be one. So the greater-than comparison is not correct.

Finally, if you really had:

```
    exit 1
    echo "hola"
```

the echo would never be executed, because the `exit` would have happened first.

Comment: Or I assume just simply `while (($#))`

Comment: sorry that was an error when i put the code first is the echo and then the exit 1 but nothing happens, i already changed the code in the question.

Comment: @andlrc: Yeah, that would work too. Another simple one would be `for key do`

Comment: @rici But that wouldn't let you use shift and have options that takes another argument.

Comment: @user138717: With that edit, you fixed the one which was wrong, but the one which was right is now wrong.

Comment: @andlrc: Neither does `*) exit;;` So they're equivalent.

Comment: @rici What I'm talking about - might not be relevant for OP - is that `for x; do` doesn't let you to have constructs like this: `pgm --size 25 --foo --bar 42`

Comment: @andlrc: That's true. In more complicated cases, you need more complicated code. Personally, I would use `getopt` or `getopts` as you suggested in a different comment for the more complicated cases, because you're unlikely to get the parsing right yourself.

Comment: @rici Yes, I suggested `getopt` since OP is using bash anyway, but somehow I managed to delete that comment :/